# Is it possible to have a high performance and high fps graphics without high CPU+GPU specs?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics

I was watching a video about .kkrieger fps game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD1wWY1YD-M) and was astounded by their incredible work to put such a complex game for such an insane small memory size (96kB). However, they consume a huge amount of CPU and GPU processing.

Then it came the following question: is it possible to develop a graphics programming engine/framework/tool for high performance and high fps without relying much on high-end CPU + GPU processing power? *I am not thinking of less ROM memory in this question, but less CPU+GPU processing power to improve the fps.*

As @Nicol-Bolas pointed out, there are many ways to see the question and my question was too broad or unfocused, so it is defined in terms of having an engine or own made code for high resolution and high fps settings without having a high CPU + GPU specs combo.

Comment: "*they consume an as incredible as an equivalent amount of CPU and GPU processing*" I find this sentence confusing. Can you reword it? Also, what is a "high-stack CPU and GPU"?

Comment: hope it fits better your understanding

Comment: these days a huge part of an exe are just the dependencies DLL and stuff linkage ... for example you can have 1MByte executable with only few KB or less of usable code  ... that is the price for libs,frameworks,higher languages and stuff. 96KByte is a lot and that is only the code/data however they most likely use much  much more RAM and procedural generated gfx. It does not require more CPU power as the init is done usually just once. To put it into perspective i once did a 3D polygonal space shooter game in 4KByte as a school project for gfx class I attended ages ago.

Comment: Google 4K or 64K demoscene and you will see what is possible... IIRC I saw Doom like game in 512Byte (bootsector game). Usually assembler is the way to shrink the size and as least DLLs as possible. The nowadays problem is we have big screen resolutions which involves much more operations and bandwith then the old 320x200x8bpp days thats why we need GPUS as CPUs usually do not keep up with it anymore. btw doomsk is like Doom + Sk or I just imagine things?

Comment: @Spektre thank you! The question is more into "how to make the same analogy but having less cpu/gpu consumption to improve fps, compared to opengl/unity tools?"; doomsk is kind of a russian-like "dooms" and dooms came from Doomsday machine from Total Annihilation rts game

Comment: @doomsk then the answer is mainly NO as for high quality/fps gfx you need high amount of processing power ... in respect to low level APIs like OpenGL/DirectX. However high level engines like Unity are most likely extremly inefficient (like most framework based code) just see the games and SW build on it [they need much higher specs  to run smoothly](https://youtu.be/tInaI3pU19Y) because of it.  There are 2 major reasons 1. big projects are hard to manage and programmers tent to use shortcuts to speed up programming at cost of efficiency

Comment: 2. nowadays new programmers usually do not understand what they really doing behind the scenes as they only use libs/packages/engines for everything especially true for Python programmers so they do not know what is effective and what not ... That is at least mine point of view and experience so take it as such. When you compare this to us old guys we started coding at very low level (asm, own rasterization and HW handling, interrupts and stuff) and later on build up to higher levels of programming which brings up knowledge the newbies do not have

Answer (score 1):

Computers are not magic. Everything they do has to come from somewhere and be the result of some process.

It is impressive to be able to generate interesting assets from algorithms. But this is a memory vs. performance tradeoff: you are exchanging small memory sizes for using up processing power to generate those assets. Essentially, algorithmic generation can be thought of as a form of data compression. And generally speaking, the bigger your compression ratios, the longer it will take to decompress the data.

If you want more stuff, it's going to cost you *something*. They choose to optimize for disk storage space, and that has costs for runtime memory and performance.

Comment: So the question remains: is it possible to get better cpu/gpu performance with specific graphics programming approach? (the memory was just the reason for the question --you can forget about it; I know about the tradeoffs)

Comment: @doomsk: "Better cpu/gpu performance" than what? If you take away the one example you gave, then what are you trying to improve relative to?

Comment: instead of having less rom memory usage, have better performance than using opengl/unity (read my question entirely, please), that is having less cpu/gpu power consumption as compared with the standard tools.

Comment: @doomsk: "Power consumption" and *performance* are very different things. Performance-per-watt used is an entirely different thing to optimize for compared to just trying to be as fast as possible. So which one are you asking about?

Comment: @doomsk: That is, are you asking if it is possible to make something *faster* than existing engines, such that they use the available CPU/GPU better than them? Or are you asking if you can make something more *efficient* than existing engines, such that they use less CPU/GPU computations to achieve comparable performance and graphical fidelity?

Comment: either way would achieve the same, since the final result is measured by fps, for instance, or other parameter related to the user experience.

Comment: @doomsk: No, it's not the same. If you are going for performance-per-watt, it doesn't matter what the FPS is. Such a measurement must be tempered by how much power is being consumed. If you're going for overall performance, then you don't even bother to look at power consumption.

Comment: I see. In this case it should be overall performance, because fps matters for users trying to use/play some application using graphics.

Comment: @doomsk: You can achieve any framerate you like, so long as you're willing to sacrifice quality. So... what *exactly* are we talking about here? It seems to me that you keep wanting to dance around the *real* question: can a person hand-code a game that out-performs the equivalent game made in an engine? This depends on a lot of things: the game in question, the hardware in question, the engine in question, what "out-performs" means, etc. It cannot be answered generally, only in specific cases.

Comment: maybe for an expert like yourself it's clear the point. As your answer shows a shallow response we have to figure out on this comments how to understand each other. So now I got it and the question should be: is it possible to get a high resolution high fps graphics using some approach on existing engines/tools or using own made code without having a super CPU+GPU hardware combo?